# CakePHP hasOne-belongsTo relationship, how to look up and insert foreign key from user input?

Tags: cakephp, model, foreign-keys, relationship, model-associations

I have two tables:

```
Property (..., postcode_id, ...)
Postcode (id, postcode, latitude, longitude)
```

The relationship:

```
class Property extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Postcode' => array(
            'className' => 'Postcode'
        )
    );

class Postcode extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Property' => array(
            'className' => 'Property'
       )
    );
```

What I'd like to happen:

1. Enter a postcode in the Property add form.
2. Check entered postcode is in the Postcode table.
3. If not, so some logic (possibly add it, just return validation error for now).
4. If so, then record the Postcode.id in Properties.postcode_id (the foreign key).

I can't figure out the best way to do this with cake. A custom Property validation function that does the check and adds it to data to be added? Or in beforeValidation? Or does Cake deal with this?

Thanks!

## EDIT

### Based on the answer, I think this is the best solution...

I think this is the better way to do it, as it validates too. Thanks Anubhav for the putting me on the right track!

As per Anubhav's answer, in the Postcode model:

```
public function checkPostcode($postcode = null){
    $record = $this->find('first', array(
            'conditions'=>array('postcode' => $postcode),
            'fields' => array('id')
        ));
    if (!empty($record)){
        return $record['Postcode']['id'];
    } else {
        return false;
        // Logic for finding and adding new postcode
    } 
}
```

But and in the Property model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'postcode' => array(
        'exists' => array(
            'rule' => 'postcodeExists',
            'message' => 'Postcode does not exist'
        )
    )
);

public function postcodeExists($check) {
    $id = $this->Postcode->checkPostcode($check);
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['Property']['postcode_id'] = $id;
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    unset($this->data['Property']['postcode']);
}
```

By modifying the values to save here, the controller is kept skinny, and, rather than making sure postcode is real then finding the id, both are done at once, so only one query is needed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How could I find the record for the postcode the user input in the Propery add form in the Postcode table, and, if it exists there, put the ID of that record in the postcode_id foreign key field in the Property table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps:

Step 1: Create one action in Postcode.php

```
function checkPostcode($postcodeValue = null){
  $returnData = $this->find('first',
                array('conditions'=>array('postcode'=>$postcodeValue),
                      'fields'=>array('id'))
                      );
  if(!empty($returnData)){
   return $returnData['Postcode']['id'];
  }else{
   $saveData['Postcode']['postcode'] = $postcodeValue;
   $this->save($saveData);
   return $this->getLastInsertID();
  } 
 }
```

The above function will check postcode from postcode model and insert postcode if not exist and returns the id of postcode table for corresponding row.

Step 2: Call this function controller action as

```
function someFuntion(){
        $postcode_id = $this->Postcode->checkPostcode($userInputPostcodeHere);
        // Write code to save property here 
    }
```

Hope this will give you some idea about the logic...

Comment: What's the reason behind checkPostcode($postcodeValue = null) instead of checkPostcode($postcodeValue)?

Also, calling the function would have to take place after the postcode field is validated as being in postcode format, so would it be called in the Property model? And if so, as a custom validation function, or in afterValidation?

Thanks!

Comment: Point number 1 checkPostcode($postcodeValue = null) so that if called without parameter does not give fatal error, Point number 2 it will called after the validation from controller action

Comment: To call it, it had to be $this->Property->Postcode->function, other than that, works great, thanks! Do you know how to accommodate for this for edit? Having a 'Postcode.postcode' field shows the current one, but it needs to be Property.postcode in order to find the Postcode.id, as you described above. Is there a best practice way of doing this? Maybe Property.postcode field, filled with the Postcode.postcode value?

Comment: @StringsOnFire I m getting your point for edit? pls tell me in laymen language.

Comment: i mean pls elaborate your question?

Comment: For edit, please see the link in my previous comment for the full question. I answered it, but would appreciate it if there's a better solution. Apart from one issue in a previous comment, your solution is perfect for adding a new Property with the correct postcode linked.

Comment: About Point 2, it does not validate. Cake will validate when running the save(). This means it runs the find etc with unvalidated data, so the logic is correct, but I think there is a better place to do it

Comment: true, validate is called before save and update, in case of find you are extracting data from database and there is no point of validating data at that point of time. I have just showed you the implementation, your question can be solved by millions of different approach, at the end of the day you have to decide which approach you want. In the last I just wanted to say always specify your requirement clearly so that it can answered accurately. thanks